# Sorry, user {USER_1} is not allowed to execute '/bin/su {USER_2}' as root on {SERVER}

Tags: sudo

My command `sudo /bin/su USER_2` fails while `sudo /bin/su - USER_2` successes.

> Sorry, user USER_1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/su USER_2' as root on SERVER.

When checking `sudo -l`:

```
USER_1@SERVER:~:$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for USER_1 on SERVER:
    syslog=auth, log_year, logfile=/var/log/sudo.log, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES
    LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

User USER_1 may run the following commands on SERVER:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL, !/usr/bin/sudoedit, !/usr/sbin/visudo, !/sbin/sulogin, !/sbin/sushell, !/bin/su, !/bin/su -, /bin/su [-] *, !/bin/su - *root, !/bin/su root, !/sbin/insmod, !/sbin/rmmod, !/sbin/depmod, !/sbin/modprobe, !/sbin/shutdown,
        !/sbin/poweroff, !/usr/bin/reboot, !/usr/bin/consolehelper, !/usr/bin/halt, !/sbin/init
```

It seems that USER_1 has permission to run `!/bin/su, !/bin/su -`, `/bin/su [-] *`.

(What does `!` mean?: `not`)

It should allow both `/bin/su USER` and `/bin/su - USER`.

Why does `sudo su USER_2` fail?

Comment: The exclamation mark means "not". user1 cannot run `su` (with the given option and argument patterns) under `sudo`.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. But it still doesn't solve this.. `[-]` means optional, right? It should allow both `/bin/su *` and `/bin/su - *`

Comment: `?` is optional. `[...]` is a set or range of characters.

Comment: @muru Then does `/bin/su [-] *` mean that only `/bin/su - *` is allowed? What's different when writing `/bin/su - *`. I checked that `/bin/su --login *` also fails.

Comment: No difference. Your rules as written only allow `/bin/su -` followed by some argument (which is problem, because I think `su - -c bash` should work)

Comment: I don't see why you would want to run `sudo su` in the first place. If you are USER1 and you want to run commands or start a shell as USER2 then just use `sudo -u USER2 {command...}` or `sudo -su USER2` or (for a login shell) `sudo -iu USER2`. None of these three commands needs to use the `su` command at all, and then you don't need to allow USER1 any access to root whatsoever

Comment: You have a trivial escape to root for USER1 in that configuration. `sudo -s` will give you a root shell

Comment: @roaima Yes, that's right and thanks for your comments. But could you please take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1648260/why-giving-an-environment-variable-to-sudo-su-fails ? I know there are other good ways but I'm currently studying over sudo things..

Comment: No, you're completely missing the point. If `sudo -s` gives USER1 a root shell then _none of the other restrictions you apply to USER1 are relevant_.